# Equivalent for Merge with output clause in SQL Server to Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, merge, common-table-expression, temp-tables

I want to insert values based on below code to a temporary table in postgresql

```
declare @output table (AuditScratchID bigint, AuditID bigint);

merge table atb
 using (select 
            s.ID
            ....
            ....
            ....
        from @temporaryTableVariable s
            inner join ....
...............
..............

        ) as s
 on 1 = 2 -- Impossible Condition so they never match
 when not matched then
    insert (.....)
    values (.....)
    output s.ID, inserted.ID
    into @output;
```

Just to mention, how can I correlate values into temporary table

Comment: I don't understand what that MERGE is supposed to do if you force it to never match? Isn't that a simple `insert into ... select from temp_table` in the end?

Comment: It is, the op has even stated that with the comment `on 1 = 2 -- Impossible Condition so they never match`

Comment: @Andronicus: the question is: why? Why is this necessary in SQL Server instead of a simply `insert into .. select from ...`?

Comment: I am doing a migration from SQL Server to PostgreSQL. Client has such code written, hence i wanted to know how can i handle output clause and insert record in PostgreSQL

Comment: the point is to have a matching/map/relation table with source iDs and inserted new iDs. possible use is to keep historical tracks of data movements, to be able to go backwards, or analysis of movements in time. Here it is from scracthAudit to Audit. The solution could be to insert in the destination table the original source iD key

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand the use of MERGE to begin with.

This seems like a straightforward `insert ... select`. To see the inserted rows, use the `returning` clause

```
insert into atb (...)
select ... columns ...
from some_table
  join other_table on ...
returning *
```